# Multiple computers in SBS domain that need a Remote Desktop Connection with a sub domain

Tags: windows-sbs, a-record, rdc

I've been searching the internet for a while for this answer.

I have a bunch of computers that are part of a small business server domain and would like to be able to connect to each one individually with remote desktop connection using a subdomain, like:

computer1.mydomain.org
computer2.mydomain.org

etc...

I can currently connect to the server easily using an A record with the subdomain pointing to the static IP address with home.mydomain.org, so computer1.home.mydomain.org would also be cool.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Which version of SBS is this? 2003? 2008? SBS 2008 has a great built-in TS Gateway and web interface, `remote.example.com` (where example.com is your external FQDN), which has everything built in. It gives you a list of all the applicable machines on the network, and off you go.

[image]
<sub>(source: [41085.org](http://www.41085.org/sbsremote.png))</sub>

If you don't have a TS gateway, then you will need to have a public IP address for each and every computer on your network, and forward the ports appropriately.

Comment: Its SBS 2003. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Yup, the feature is called Remote Web Workplace and has been around since at least SBS 2003.  Works great and more secure than opening up a pile of ports for each machine and RDP.  Check out the SBS Blog post on how it all works: http://blogs.technet.com/sbs/archive/2006/07/25/443383.aspx